# Using in operator to compare string with range of strings

Tags: kotlin, in-operator

I am using in operator to check whether a value is in range. But I am not able to understand exactly how the comparison with range of strings is done. Below are the few arguments and their output which I have tried:

```
   println("KOTLIN" in "J".."K")
false

   println("KOTLIN" in "Java".."Scala")
true

    println("KOTLIN" in "Java".."Bhuv")
false
```

Comment: It tests is "KOTLIN" is >= "J" and <= "K", using the compareTo() method of String.

Comment: I think this will make it clear what your issue is: `println("KOTLIN" in "J".."KZ")` i.e. `KOTLIN > K` and `KOTLIN < KZ`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`in` is compiled down to the following function (defined in `kotlin.ranges.Range.kt`):

```
public operator fun contains(value: T): Boolean = value >= start && value <= endInclusive
```

So `"KOTLIN" in "J".."K"` results in:

```
("J".."K").contains("KOTLIN")
```

The comparison in this case relies on normal `String` comparisons since >= and <= are compiled down to variations of `compareTo`. The implementation looks as follows:

```
public int compareTo(String anotherString) {
    int len1 = value.length;
    int len2 = anotherString.value.length;
    int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
    char v1[] = value;
    char v2[] = anotherString.value;

    int k = 0;
    while (k < lim) {
        char c1 = v1[k];
        char c2 = v2[k];
        if (c1 != c2) {
            return c1 - c2;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return len1 - len2;
}
```

So, `"KOTLIN" in "Java".."Scala"` is equal to the following:

```
"KOTLIN".compareTo("Java") >=0 && "KOTLIN".compareTo("Scala") <= 0
```

Comment: Hows the comparison for "KOTLIN" in "Java".."Scala" is done.Is every character of string is compared.And if yes with with what it is compared?

Comment: It relies on Java's String compare, I added the implementation

Answer (score 3):

Based on your question, I think you are confused about this result:

`println("KOTLIN" in "J".."K")` is `false`

Basically, if you were to sort these using Java's String comparison implementation, you would see this:

```
Bhuv
J
Java
K
KOTLIN
KZ
```

Since `K` is lexicographically before `KOTLIN`, the result you are seeing makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

Lexicographic Order aka Dictionary Order, e.g.. when scrolling down the words in a dictionary, the order of the words will be

1.Java 
2.Kotlin 
3.Scala

Hence,

(**Kotlin in Java..Scala**) will return true. 
**In normal english, the code above is stating that by using the Dictionary Order, the word Kotlin is found in between the word Java and Scala.**