# How to set enable or disable view in RecyclerView Adapter Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In my application, I want to use `Recyclerview` and show some data from the server. 
The server sends me **hours**, and I should check the current hour. I should set alpha for this if the server time is less than the current time.

**I write the below codes in Adapter:**

```
class HoursAdapter constructor(private val items: MutableList<Data>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<HoursAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var binding: ItemVisitHoursBinding
    private lateinit var context: Context

    private val hoursList = mutableListOf<String>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        binding = ItemVisitHoursBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        context = parent.context
        return ViewHolder()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) = holder.bind(items[position])

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    inner class ViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "NotifyDataSetChanged")
        fun bind(item: Data) {
            binding.apply {
                // item.hour ==> show such as this format : 7-8
                hoursTxt.text = item.hour
                //Disable previous hours
                val endHour = item.hour.split("-")[1]

                Log.e("HoursLog", "End : $endHour --- Now : ${nowJustHour()}")

                if (endHour < nowJustHour()) {
                    root.alpha = 0.4f
                } else {
                    root.alpha = 1.0f
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Show this line into logcat:**

```
End : 8 --- Now : 11
End : 9 --- Now : 11
End : 10 --- Now : 11
End : 11 --- Now : 11
End : 12 --- Now : 11
End : 13 --- Now : 11
End : 14 --- Now : 11
End : 15 --- Now : 11
End : 16 --- Now : 11
End : 17 --- Now : 11
End : 18 --- Now : 11
End : 19 --- Now : 11
End : 20 --- Now : 11
End : 21 --- Now : 11
End : 22 --- Now : 11
End : 23 --- Now : 11
```

My code's result is as follows: 
[image: Screenshot of output]

Now it's 11 (o'clock), but the app just set alpha for one time! It should set alpha for **7 - 8 - 9 - 10**. 
Why just set alpha for 10?

How can I fix it and set alpha for all of less time?

Comment: Check whether this function ```nowJustHour()```  returns integer type value not string type and ```endHour```  this variable was in type of Integer not of string.  If both the value was in string then it performs lexicographical comparison not numerical comparison. Also if you could provide code for the activity/fragment where you have used this ```HoursAdapter ``` Adapter, it would be helpful for further investigation of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following if-else in the bind method:

```kotlin
if (endHour.toInt() < nowJustHour().toInt()) {
    root.alpha = 0.4f
} else {
    root.alpha = 1.0f
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `endHour` of your code is a string, and I'm assuming `nowJustHour()` also returns a string. When you use a relational operator to compare strings, a comparator method is called to compare them. A variation of this method looks like this:

```kotlin
public int compareTo(String anotherString) {
    int len1 = value.length;
    int len2 = anotherString.value.length;
    int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
    char v1[] = value;
    char v2[] = anotherString.value;

    int k = 0;
    while (k < lim) {
        char c1 = v1[k];
        char c2 = v2[k];
        if (c1 != c2) {
            return c1 - c2;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return len1 - len2;
}
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46764287/8192914) to learn more about how comparisons work.

As you can see, it will not give true for `"8" < "11"`. So you have to parse those strings to integer (or long/double) before comparing them.